# How to write a DELETE request in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating a simple Wiki with Express and Node.js. So far, my app has an index listing all wiki pages, an add_page view and a single_page view. My next task is to add the capability to delete/edit pages, but I don't know how to write the code.

Here are my routes in app.js:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/add', routes.new_form);
app.post('/add_page', routes.submit_form);
app.get('/wiki/:title', wiki.show);
```

I was thinking I would add a new HTTP method for DELETE:

`app.delete('/wiki/:title', wiki.delete);`

In my routes/index.js file I would create a new `exports` that would hold the logic to delete the page.

```
exports.delete = function(req,res) {
  var page = req.params.title;  
  // delete this object in mongo database;
}
```

Does Express have an HTTP delete method? Or would it be better to use a GET method to grab the page I want to delete? And how do I write the exports function so that it removes the page in MongoDB and views/index.js?

Answer (score -1):

Express has both `delete` and `del` (recommended, because `delete` is a reserved word).